# Create folder inside another folder using node

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am using node js to create a folder inside another folder. Below is my code -

In this i am first creating a folder with oppId and then i am trying to create 2nd folder as accId under each oppId folder.

The issue which i am facing is all the folders are being created in one directory

```
var stream  = fs.createReadStream('./test.csv')
.pipe(csv({headers: true}))
.on('data',function(data){
  accID = data.Id;
  oppId = data.AccountId;
  var dir = './'+oppId+'/';
  var dir1 = './'+oppId+'/'+accID+'/';
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(oppId);
  }
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(accID);
  }
})
.on('end',function(data){
  console.log('read finished');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dir = './'+oppId+'/';
var dir1 = './'+oppId+'/'+accID+'/';
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.